# How to apply a padding to every element in a block?

Tags: html, css

I'm searching a way to apply padding to every element in a block.

Like in this example block, I want every element to get a padding value.

```css
#informations {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

#informations > * > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* I want here a way to apply padding to every element in the big container */
}

#child_inf_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="informations">

  <div>
    <a id="child_inf_1">This is hot</a>
    <div id="child_inf_2">
      <a>Tepid hot</a>
      <a>This is tepid</a>
      <a>Tepid cold</a>
    </div>
    <a id="child_inf_3">This is cold</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could here use `#selected_elt > * > * {padding}` but this is a very unstable solution and dependant of the number of children of every container.

Comment: Wouldn't `#selected_elt *` do it? No need to specify direct children if you want to select everything. (Though there are likely better approaches, depending on what you are building. `*` should be avoided where possible)

Comment: you could just use a class and apply it to all elements?

Comment: yes but i have to go over each element so this is not comfortable but it should work @mrpbennett.

Comment: Applying the padding to the parent will have the same impact, and will remove the problem of child's depth

Comment: No, I want each single element to have a padding value. Not only the parents. Every parent and children !

Comment: So Miguel Angel answer is what you need `#informations *, #informations` will select every element in `#informations` and `#informations` himself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that **everything** use padding you can normalize your css with:

```
* {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Like this:

```css
* {
   padding: 5px;
} 

#informations {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

#informations > * > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* I want here a way to apply padding to every element in the big container */
}

#child_inf_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="informations">

  <div>
    <a id="child_inf_1">This is hot</a>
    <div id="child_inf_2">
      <a>Tepid hot</a>
      <a>This is tepid</a>
      <a>Tepid cold</a>
    </div>
    <a id="child_inf_3">This is cold</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution could be apply the style to all (*) inside the #informations div, like this:

```
#informations > * {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```css
#informations > * {
padding: 5px;
}

#informations {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

#informations > * > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* I want here a way to apply padding to every element in the big container */
}

#child_inf_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="informations">

  <div>
    <a id="child_inf_1">This is hot</a>
    <div id="child_inf_2">
      <a>Tepid hot</a>
      <a>This is tepid</a>
      <a>Tepid cold</a>
    </div>
    <a id="child_inf_3">This is cold</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it works with the `* {padding}` but the `#selected_elt{padding}` definitely don't do the job for each element. It only applies on every direct descendant of the parent selected element. And what about the descendants of the descendants of the selected elements ? (got it ?)

Answer (score 0):

Close! `#selected_elt *` will target any child element of `#selected_elt`.

Read more on selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors).

*Also, as someone else has already mentioned, use the universal selector is quite a blunt approach. Please consider extracting these styles into a class you can apply to the descendants of `#selected_elt` for a more sustainable alternative.*

```css
#informations {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

#informations * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  /* I want here a way to apply padding to every element in the big container */
}

#child_inf_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="informations">

  <div>
    <a id="child_inf_1">This is hot</a>
    <div id="child_inf_2">
      <a>Tepid hot</a>
      <a>This is tepid</a>
      <a>Tepid cold</a>
    </div>
    <a id="child_inf_3">This is cold</a>
  </div>
</div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587939/how-to-apply-a-padding-to-every-element-in-a-block#
```